# C# - Cambiar individualmente el color de letras de un label

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me atoré en esta parte de mi código por que me di en la interrogante de si es posible cambiar individualmente el color de una letra dentro de un label por ejemplo. (Si es necesario cambiar el tipo de contenedor para hacer esta lógica también me ayudaría)

Tengo un textbox y un label. En el label hay una frase y el textbox valida que lo que se introduce en él, sea igual a lo que está en el label.

Hasta ahora ya he logrado que mi textbox valide que se introduzcan correctamente las mismas palabras que hay en el label hasta el final.

Ahora me gustaría hacer que cuando introduzco la primera letra correcta de la frase del label en el textbox, la primera letra del label cambie de color a verde por ejemplo (indicando que la primera letra está bien) y que si se pone otra letra, la primera letra del label se ponga en rojo por ejemplo. (esto lo necesito en tiempo real, así que ya tengo un timer para esta validación)

Y así sucesivamente, si la primera letra introducida en el textbox es la misma que la primera letra de la frase en el label, entonces que se pinte a verde, y que esa primera letra del label se quede de verde y que se pueda pasar la validación con la segunda letra y así sucesivamente hasta que todas las letras del label se pinten de verde. (Esto claro mientras el textbox aún mantiene las letras introducida anteriormente)

En este caso es por palabras, ya que mi textbox se limpia cuando la primera palabra es introducida correctamente y se toca el espacio para seguir con la siguiente palabra.

¿es posible hacer esto mediante un label? ¿o puedo cambiar el contenedor para aplicar esta lógica?

También ya tengo hecho un arreglo "Chars" que ya tiene almacenada la frase que se debe escribir carácter por carácter. (Si ayuda en algo)

Mi código completo hasta ahora:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Globales        

    string[] cuotes = {"texto 1", "texto 2", "De noche, todos los gatos son pardos"};

    string cuote = "";        

    Random rndword = new Random();
    int randomword;

    int points = 0;
    int time = 0;
    int estado = 0;
    int circuit = 0;
    

    //Globales

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();            
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        

    }

    private void btnReady_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        typechar.Text = "";
       
        typechar.AutoSize = Enabled;            
        typechar.MaximumSize = new Size(400, 91);
        typechar.Location = new Point(120,115);            

        randomword = rndword.Next(0, cuotes.Length);
        typechar.Text = cuotes[randomword];
        cuote = cuotes[randomword];

        /*char[] chars = cuote.ToCharArray();
        
        for (int letters = 0; letters <= cuote.Length-1; letters++)
        {
            typechar.Text += chars[letters].ToString();
        }*/

        tmrGO.Start();
        tmrTL.Start();

        points = 0;
        Puntos.Text = "0";

        estado = 0;

        inputword.Enabled = true;

        time = 0;
        lefttimetext.Text = "0";

        inputword.Focus();

    }

    private void tmrGO_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] words = cuote.Split(" ");

        char[] chars = cuote.ToCharArray();
        


        if (estado == words.Length - 1)
        {

            if (inputword.Text == words[estado].ToString())
            {
                points++;
                Puntos.Text = points.ToString();
                inputword.Text = "";
                inputword.Focus();

                /*randomword = rndword.Next(1, words.Length);
                typechar.Text = words[randomword];*/

                if (estado == words.Length - 1)
                {
                    tmrGO.Enabled = false;
                    tmrTL.Enabled = false;

                    inputword.Enabled = false;

                    btnReady.Text = "NUEVA CARRERA";
                    btnReady.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    estado++;
                }

            }

        }
        else
        {

            if (inputword.Text == words[estado].ToString() + " ")
            {
                points++;
                Puntos.Text = points.ToString();
                inputword.Text = "";
                inputword.Focus();

                /*randomword = rndword.Next(1, words.Length);
                typechar.Text = words[randomword];*/

                if (estado == words.Length - 1)
                {
                    tmrGO.Enabled = false;
                    tmrTL.Enabled = false;

                    inputword.Enabled = false;

                    btnReady.Text = "NUEVA CARRERA";
                    btnReady.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    estado++;
                }

            }

        }                      
   
    }

    private void tmrTL_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        time++;

        lefttimetext.Text = time.ToString();
    }
}
```

¿Dónde podría aplicar esta lógica?, ¿en el timer quizá?

Gracias de antemano si me pueden ayudar. Saludos.

Comment: deje de leer al principio, porque con un label no vas a poder, porque no tiene caracteristicas para eso. Si podrias con multiples labels, o con algun control propietario de alguna libreria. Y todavia es mas complicado en windows form.. en wpf lo tendrias mas simple...

Comment: entiendo que la propiedad `ForeColor` de un `Label` afecta a todas las letras del texto. Entonces, se podría crear una lista de objetos Label y cada Label tiene un caracter de la palabra.

Comment: Ya que no puedes con un label, una opción que puedes usar es un `RichTextBox` que te da mayor control sobre el texto. Solo tendrías que evitar que el usuario lo modifique directamente.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí tienes un ejemplo. Dado que la propiedad `ForeColor` del objeto `Label` afecta a todas las letras del texto, usamos un `Panel` como contenedor de varios objetos `Label` para cada letra de la palabra.

```csharp
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ejemplo
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private string palabra = "Hola mundo";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            iniciarPanelPalabra();
        }

        private void iniciarPanelPalabra()
        {
            panelPalabra.BackColor = Color.AntiqueWhite;
            for (int i = 0; i < palabra.Length; i++)
            {
                Label label = new Label();
                label.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 16.2F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
                label.Text = palabra[i].ToString();
                label.Size = new Size(32, 32);
                label.Location = new Point(32 * i, 0);
                panelPalabra.Controls.Add(label);
            }
        }

        private void textPalabra_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var letras = panelPalabra.Controls;
            var input = textPalabra.Text;
            if (input.Length == 0)
            {
                foreach (Control c in letras)
                {
                    c.ForeColor = Color.Black;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // color rojo o verde para las letras
                for (int i = 0; i < input.Length && input.Length <= letras.Count; i++)
                {
                    var label = letras[i];
                    label.ForeColor = input[i].ToString() == label.Text ? Color.Green : Color.Red;
                }

                // color negro para el resto de letras
                if (input.Length < letras.Count)
                {
                    for (int i = input.Length; i < letras.Count; i++)
                    {
                        letras[i].ForeColor = Color.Black;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

En un lugar de crear un array de tipo `Control[]` o `Label[]`, uso la propiedad `Controls` del objeto `Panel`.

El resultado final se muestra en esta animación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]